# Fiber Optical and 80Gbps MTP/MPO?

Tags: cables, optical-fibre

I am trying to get a cable solution to output 80Gbps of data. My FPGA is trying to input/output data. It has QSFP-DD cages. Fiber SFP+ cables (50um and multimode) need to interface to this. From my search online, it doesn't appear anything fiber can breakout from QSFP-DD to 8x 10G, but if I use a MPO/MTP, it seems like I can breakout from QSFP-DD to 8x 25G.

If I specify my FPGA to output 10G (which is can. Its the ADM-PCIE-9V5), can I make a custom cable of a QSFP-DD MPO/MTP to 8X 10G and does the fiber cable automatically convert to that?

It seems like I may need a MPO/MTP cassette, but I couldn't find any that breakout to 16 ports. Only 12 and 24.

Thanks

EDIT: More context: I am thinking of using a QSFP-DD SR8 with a fiber breakout cable to 8x 10G SFP+ TRXs/Modules. The QSFP-DD is rated up to 400G, but I am curious if it can "do" 80G if the FPGA and data is sending it at that rate.

Essentially [this QSFP-DD connector](https://www.fs.com/products/110528.html?attribute=3734&id=175937) with this [SFP+](https://www.fs.com/products/110528.html?attribute=3734&id=175937) TRX. Connected by this [cable](https://www.fs.com/products/118112.html?attribute=4118&id=182810)

Comment: 80 gigabits per second, I presume.

Comment: @jsotola 80 Gbps of data. apologies. Ill edit my post to reflect that.